# How do I use MappingCharFilter with Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene.net

I am running .NET 4.5 and Lucene.Net 3.0.3 and trying to "fix" the `ASCIIFoldingFilter` for umlauts-behavior (as `ä` gets converted to `a` instead of `ae` - and searches with eg `Geschäft` and `Geschaeft` should work alike).

I have already implemented my own analyzer:

```
public sealed class LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer : Lucene.Net.Analysis.KeywordAnalyzer
{
    public override Lucene.Net.Analysis.TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        var keywordTokenizer = base.TokenStream(fieldName, reader);
        var lowerCaseFilter = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.LowerCaseFilter(keywordTokenizer);
        var asciiFoldingFilter = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.ASCIIFoldingFilter(lowerCaseFilter);

        return asciiFoldingFilter;
    }
}
```

Now I have tried to add a `Lucene.Net.Analysis.MappingCharFilter`-instance like:

```
public sealed class LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer : Lucene.Net.Analysis.KeywordAnalyzer
{
    public override Lucene.Net.Analysis.TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        var keywordTokenizer = base.TokenStream(fieldName, reader);
        var lowerCaseFilter = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.LowerCaseFilter(keywordTokenizer);
        var mappingCharFilter = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.MappingCharFilter(/* get map from somewhere*/, ???);
        var asciiFoldingFilter = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.ASCIIFoldingFilter(lowerCaseFilter);

        return asciiFoldingFilter;
    }
}
```

But how do I inject either a `CharStream`- or `TextReader`-instance? I just have a `Lucene.Net.Analysis.TokenStream`-instance (either `Lucene.Net.Analysis.LowerCaseFilter` or `base.TokenStream()`) ...
Any chance to get this to work, except writing a custom`Lucene.Net.Analysis.TokenFilter` which does the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented my own `Lucene.Net.Analysis.TokenFilter`:

```
public sealed class UmlautsFoldingFilter : Lucene.Net.Analysis.TokenFilter
{
    private readonly Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenattributes.ITermAttribute _termAttribute;
    private char[] _output = new char[512];
    private int _outputPosition;

    public UmlautsFoldingFilter(Lucene.Net.Analysis.TokenStream input)
        : base(input)
    {
        this._termAttribute = this.AddAttribute<Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenattributes.ITermAttribute>();
    }

    public override bool IncrementToken()
    {
        if (!this.input.IncrementToken())
        {
            return false;
        }

        var termBuffer = this._termAttribute.TermBuffer();
        var termLength = this._termAttribute.TermLength();

        this.FoldUmlaut(termBuffer,
                        termLength);

        this._termAttribute.SetTermBuffer(this._output,
                                          0,
                                          this._outputPosition);

        return true;
    }

    private void FoldUmlaut(char[] termBuffer,
                            int termLength)
    {
        var targetSize = 4 * termLength;
        if (this._output.Length < targetSize)
        {
            this._output = new char[Lucene.Net.Util.ArrayUtil.GetNextSize(targetSize)];
        }
        this._outputPosition = 0;
        for (var index = 0;
             index < termLength;
             ++index)
        {
            var ch = termBuffer[index];
            switch (ch)
            {
                case 'Ä':
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'A';
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'E';
                    continue;
                case 'Ö':
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'O';
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'E';
                    continue;
                case 'Ü':
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'U';
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'E';
                    continue;
                case 'ä':
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'a';
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'e';
                    continue;
                case 'ö':
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'o';
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'e';
                    continue;
                case 'ü':
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'u';
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = 'e';
                    continue;
                default:
                    this._output[this._outputPosition++] = ch;
                    continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here an answer to an old question, but might be nevertheless relevant, as the original answer does not show the use of the NormalizeCharMap in Lucene.net.
In your Analyzer class override also the InitReader like this:

```
public override TextReader InitReader(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        NormalizeCharMap.Builder builder = new NormalizeCharMap.Builder();
        builder.Add("Ä", "AE");
        builder.Add("ä", "ae");
        builder.Add("Ö", "OE");
        builder.Add("ö", "oe");
        builder.Add("Ü", "UE");
        builder.Add("ü", "ue");
        return new MappingCharFilter(builder.Build(), reader);
     }
```

This should give you the required replacements/normlizations.

Comment: how can i update TokenStream to include these characters ?